# Share a same popup window among different addin instances

Tags: popup, local-storage, ms-office, office-js, window.open

I am making an Excel add-in by [Excel JavaScript API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-javascript-programming-overview?product=excel). There is a button in this add-in, clicking on it launches `popup = window.open("https://localhost:3000/#/new/", "popup", "width=1000, height=1100")` and popups a browser window.

Closing the workbook or the add-in will NOT systematically close the popup. So at the moment, if I open a workbook and the add-in again, and click on the button, **another** browser window will popup.

I am thinking **if it is possible to always use the same popup for all the excel/add-in instances**. We could use `localstorage` to share information among different excel/add-in instances, but I am not sure if it is possible to save the popup/window there.

Does anyone have any good idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For Office Add-ins, you should be using the built in [Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.dialog). This API ensures popups are properly handled regardless of platform (i.e. across browsers, mobile and desktop clients).

The Dialog object supports a `close` method, allowing you to close any open dialogs from the parent taskpane.

Comment: My tests show that closing the taskpane or excel brutally will NOT close systematically the Dialog, so my question also applies to Dialog: How to share a same Dialog window among different addin instances?

Comment: You cannot reuse any orphaned windows because you no longer have a handle for them. You will need logic within your dialog page that checks for its parent and automatically closes if the parent vanishes. You might be able to do this using the `messageparent` method.

Comment: What would be an efficient way for the Dialog page to send `messageparent` periodically to check?